# Updating an Excel Spreadsheet from a Text Box on a Userform

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

Good Evening All,

Apologies again for what will probably be another novice question.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a list of documents on containing information like Document Number, Title, Author etc. This spreadsheet is linked into my Userform so I can obtain all of the information for a document and display it nicely in my form.

What I now want to do is to be able to edit the data in the spreadsheet from my form. For example, I have a cell for "Comments". I would like to be able to open my form, type a comment in the comments box, and it insert that comment into the Comments Cell on the spreadsheet. Then, on next use when I open the form to display the data of that document, the comment reloads and allows me to continue making additional comments.

I have tried the following code:

```
    Private Sub txtcomment_Change()

    Dim DOCUMENT As String
    DOCUMENT = TPForm.TP_No_text.Text
 
    Dim Search_Range As Range
    Set Search_Range = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B1:v107")

    Dim matchRow
    matchRow = Application.Match(DOCUMENT, Search_Range.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
    Dim comment As Range
    Set comment = Search_Range.Cells(matchRow, 21)
    comment.Value = txtcomment.Text

    End If
    End Sub
```

This sort of works, when I enter a comment into the comment text box it inserts it into the cell for the document info I have open - but then if I close that user form and I open another document into the Userform it puts that same comment in that document as well and the next one and next one. Then when I delete it directly out of the spreadsheet and reopen the Userform, the comment is still there.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Apologies if I haven't been very clear.
Thanks
James

Comment: What is `TPForm`?  Is that the userform?  It's typically safer to use `Me` inside the userform to refer to itself.  "Then when I delete it directly out of the spreadsheet and reopen the Userform, the comment is still there"  - where is "there"? - on the sheet, or in the userform ?  When unloading/loading a record into your form, you might want to set a flag to prevent these "auto-updates" from firing during the unloading/loading of the record.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, the 'TPForm' is the name of the Userform that the textbox is on, so 'TPForm.TP_No_Text' is basically the macro looking for the Document Title in the Spreadsheet. When I say "there" I mean there as in, still in the Userform, even though I've deleted it from the spreadsheet. 
How do you set a flag as you mention

Comment: You can set a Global variable like `bUpdating` for example, and set the to True when loading a record.  Inside `txtcomment_Change` you can check that before making any changes.

Comment: Okay - would this solve the issues I'm having?

Comment: What you posted looks OK by itself, but I can't see the rest of your code, so I can only guess at what the problem is.

Comment: Okay - that is all the code I have for the text box - should there be more to it? How do I put bUpdating  code into it?

Comment: `If bUpdating Then Exit Sub`  Don't forget to set `bUpdating` back to False when you're done loading/unloading the record.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I don't actually know what bUpdating does? and how do I set it back to false?
I have inserted the `If bUpdating then Exit Sub` into the code and it partially works, that it doesn't update every entry I open with the comment in the text box...the same comment is still in the text for every entry I open.

Comment: Can you post the code which loads a record from the sheet into your userform?